# How do I convert a PySpark Dataframe to something that R can recognise in DataBricks?

Tags: python, r, azure, pyspark, databricks

I have accessed my Azure database using Python and I would like to now recycle some R code to continue this analysis. Is there anyway I can swap between the two languages? For example, import a dataframe in python and use the dataframe using R code.

**Data is imported into a PySpark dtaframe**

```
venue_list_raw = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("path.csv")
```

**Continue work in R, e.g.**

```
venue_list <- venue_list_raw %>% mutate(postcode_short = substr(postcode,1,nchar(str_extract(postcode,"(\\w+)"))+2))
```

I have already tried:

```
%r
library(SparkR)
library(dbplyr)
# collect the data from Spark to local
# convert Spark DataFrame into R data frame
mailing_list_raw_r <- collect(mailing_list_raw)
display(mailing_list_raw_r)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JH2021, using `collect()` you can get the desired result? what are you looking for other than that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing the above in databricks, you can do it by creating temporary view for the dataframe. Then access that view in R like below.

[image]

`df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp1")`

**Code:**

```
df2 <- tableToDF("view_name")
display(df2)
```

[image]

Or like below also.

```
sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")
r_df <- collect(spark_read_table(
  sc   = sc,
  name = "temp1"
))
display(r_df)
```

[image]